# 2008 Subaru Impreza 2.5i : Water is dripping onto the ground from underneath the drivers side

Tags: subaru, water

I have recently encountered an issue my car in which I notice water puddling underneath the car between the driver and passenger doors.

It seems to be pure water and not coolant or oil. I haven't been running the AC. The area circled in the photograph remains wet to the touch when not in use.

Any ideas on what the issue is?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The A/C could still be coming on even if you haven't pressed the button - e.g if you have it in Defrost or Auto mode. And the water looks like it's in the correct place for the AC Drain Hose. If you can catch a drip in your hand, and it's cold, then that's confirmation.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I just noticed upon further inspection that my passenger floor mat is wet as well. I set my climate control dial to the middle which i believe will prevent the a/c from coming on.

Comment: hmm... A wet passenger floor mat points to a broken heater matrix, rather than anything AC related. Check to see if there is water up behind the glovebox.

Comment: I should have stated that I meant the rear passenger mat on the drivers side. The glove box area is dry.